# El simulador presenta la pantalla en negro al darle Play con SWIFT 3 y Xcode 8

Tags: swift3

Soy nuevo en esta herramienta pero siguiendo los pasos del curso que tome y queriendo desplegar un string de "Hola Mundo" en el simulador se ejecuta y empieza a cargar las siguientes pantallas en este orden:

[image: Presenta una imagen en el centro de la pantalla como si estuviera cargando pero la pantalla sigue en color negro....]

[image: Y luego aparece la imagen con varias aplicaciones simulando un iPhone y nunca presenta el Print que puse de "Hola Mundo"]

Alguien podría ayudarme para ver que tengo que configurar y que presente la pantalla en blanco con lo que estoy mandando en la instrucción PRINT.

De antemano les agradezco su atención a esta duda.

Answer (score 0):

investigue un poco y al parecer es un problema con la instalación de Xcode, ¿De casualidad instalaste una versión beta antes o desde un archivo descargado de internet en lugar de instalar desde la app store?

Una solución seria borrar el archivo de xcode beta u otros xcode que tengas en tu carpeta de apps.

Otra posible solución y la que mejor serviría, seria borrar y desinstalar todo lo referente a xcode y volverlo a instalar desde la appstore

Te paso el link del grupo oficial de Apple, donde encontré la respuesta:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48540

Nos vemos en nuestro curso en Udemy, ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Print es para imprimir por consola, no visualmente, para ello necesitas usar una etiqueta, botón, campo de texto, etc.
Usa el Storyboard y el archivo enlazado al ViewController para ello.
Te recomiendo que mires algunos tutoriales básicos de Swift y de Xcode.